# Admin Notifications in Firebase Firestore

Tags: firebase, function, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any easy way admin to get notification whenever a new document added to fire store, we are completed the shopping app with android studio and fire base. user successfully placing orders but admin has to go fire base console and to check if any new order.

please help me to get notified by email or any other method. fire base functions may be the solution but i am completely new to functions.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built into Firestore to send an email when a new document is added.

But you can use the Firestore integration with Cloud Functions to trigger such an email. In fact, that is precisely what the Firebase [trigger email](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-send-email) extension does. It's a click-to-install extension, so I recommend giving that a try and see if it fits your needs.

Comment: I am about to install in trigger email but firebase says that this feature is for use along with sendgrid,mailgun etc.

Comment: That is correct. There is no built-in ability to send your own email, so you'll need to provide your own SMTP provider for both the extension and Cloud Functions.